LibCurl code:35 - Message: schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
When I execute my script, I encounter the error LibCurl code:35 - Message: schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed . I've already set the following options in my C++ code to emulate the behavior of the curl command with the -k option:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L)
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L)

However, using the curl command with the -k option directly from the command line yields the expected results.
Any idea what can further be added in my script to further mimic the behavior of the curl command with the -k option?
I added curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L) to see further details. Below is the output of that option.
Trying x.x.x.x:443...

Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)

schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate

schannel: using IP address, SNI is not supported by OS.

schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Closing connection 0


EDIT:
Note: This is an example code. The server which is producing the error doesn't require any authentication. This code also returns the same error as mentioned in the original post. These are all the CURL options that are in my project as well. Using www.example.com here just as an example.
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 5000);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << errbuf << std::endl;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}




"When I execute my script" - which script?

It is a C++ project that is using Libcurl library. The entire project can't always be shared here do to many reasons. The question is fairly simple that I am trying to emulate the behavior of the curl command with the -k option using LibCurl library TO BYPASS THE SSL CERTIFICATE VERIFICATION. As mentioned in the original post that I have added both options from libcurl library which are responsible. My question was, what could be the reason for this error? If you have any insights beyond the conventional settings would be greatly appreciated! After all, we're all here to learn, aren't we?

A note: The generally recommended standard for code examples, [mre] (MRE), typically looks nothing like the original project code as it has been stripped down to the point where the example is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. It's very rare to still have proprietary information that needs to be protected in the code example at that point. But the real beauty of the MRE is it's hard to make a good one without reducing the noise the mistake uses to hide so much that the mistake leaps out and slaps you in the face, making it easy to fix.

The code works for me (I have a test server on localhost), it prints debug info showing that it's ignoring self-signed certificate, and in the end prints json reply. You need to be specific and include MRE, mention platforms, tools versions (maybe in the older versions protocols support is different), how you build the project, and also your server configuration. Does it work with https://example.com?

If you search for "schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed" on the Internet then you find out that Schannel likely does not support server expected TLS protocol features, the server simply drops libcurl TLS client hello.

using the curl command with the -k option directly from the command line yields the expected results.

That curl uses another backend. Look for other libcurl.dll in your OS. They are likely built with OpenSSL which TLS protocol features are almost always more actual than those of Schannel.
Try to use that libcurl supplied with curl. Or build libcurl with OpenSSL. Or install another libcurl: vcpkg install curl[openssl].

I built my libcurl using flag -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} in .cmake file, and the project requires libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libcurl.dll, and libssl-1_1-x64.dll to run

This would not report as Schannel. You libs seem to be in the DLL Hell.
